# how to make jquery target an a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have created a btn with the help of some great developers on here.

I Need to add some other functionality into it though. The problem occurs once i have several of the same btns, once clicked they all change, where as I only need the one to change..
I realise I may need to add a (this ) statement in but unsure where.

Would really appreciate it a helping hand on this,

fiddle here. please update,

http://jsfiddle.net/X39QY/

```
/*  FOLLOW BTN FUNCTIONS
===================================================================*/
$('#follow-me-btn').mouseenter(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('follow-btn1'))
    {
    $(this).css("background-color","#de2323");
    $('span.follow').text("unfollow");
    }

});

$('#follow-me-btn').mouseleave(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('follow-btn1'))
    {
    $(this).addClass("follow-btn1");
    $(this).css("background-color","#3d9223");
    $('span.follow').text("following");
    }

});

$('#follow-me-btn').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('follow-btn1'))
    {
    $(this).removeClass('follow-btn1');
    $(this).addClass('follow-btn');
    $(this).css("background-color","#bdbdbd");
    $('span.follow').text("follow");
    }
    else
    {
    $(this).addClass("follow-btn1");
    $(this).css("background-color","#3d9223");
    $('span.follow').text("following");
    }

});
```

Comment: All your event handlers are still using the ID, and only the first element is found as ID's are unique.

Comment: You are using the same id for multiple buttons. Id's need to be unique.

Comment: You don't need to use javascript to change the background color on mouse enter & mouse leave. CSS does it much nicer. :link :visited :hover and :active allow you con control this. see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/X39QY/4/

You must target only the span.follow under the current button.
By the way, it's not a good practice to have more than one container with the same ID!

```
/*  FOLLOW BTN FUNCTIONS
===================================================================*/

$('[data-follow-me-btn]').mouseenter(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('follow-btn1'))
        {
        $(this).css("background-color","#de2323");
        $(this).find('span.follow').text("unfollow");
        }

    });

    $('[data-follow-me-btn]').mouseleave(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('follow-btn1'))
        {
        $(this).addClass("follow-btn1");
        $(this).css("background-color","#3d9223");
        $(this).find('span.follow').text("following");
        }

    });

    $('[data-follow-me-btn]').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('follow-btn1'))
        {
        $(this).removeClass('follow-btn1');
        $(this).addClass('follow-btn');
        $(this).css("background-color","#bdbdbd");
        $(this).find('span.follow').text("follow");
        }
        else
        {
        $(this).addClass("follow-btn1");
        $(this).css("background-color","#3d9223");
        $(this).find('span.follow').text("following");
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

All your event handlers are using $('span.follow') selector which effects all span.follow elements in your HTML. You need to add $(this) before all of them so it can only update the text of the selected element. Also, in HTML you can not assign same ids for every element. ID has to be unique. Here is your HTML:

```
<li><a href="#" class="follow-me-btn follow-btn following charts"><span class="follow">Follow</span></a></li>

<li><a href="#" class="follow-me-btn follow-btn following charts"><span class="follow">Follow</span></a></li>

<li><a href="#" class="follow-me-btn follow-btn following charts"><span class="follow">Follow</span></a></li>

<li><a href="#" class=" follow-me-btn follow-btn following charts"><span class="follow">Follow</span></a></li>
```

Here is the js code:

```
$('.follow-me-btn').mouseenter(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('follow-btn1'))
    {
    $(this).css("background-color","#de2323");
    $(this).find('span').text("unfollow");
    }

});

$('.follow-me-btn').mouseleave(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('follow-btn1'))
    {
    $(this).addClass("follow-btn1");
    $(this).css("background-color","#3d9223");
    $(this).find('span').text("following");
    }

});

$('.follow-me-btn').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('follow-btn1'))
    {
    $(this).removeClass('follow-btn1');
    $(this).addClass('follow-btn');
    $(this).css("background-color","#bdbdbd");
    $(this).find('span').text("follow");
    }
    else
    {
    $(this).addClass("follow-btn1");
    $(this).css("background-color","#3d9223");
    $(this).find('span').text("following");
    }

});
```

And here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X39QY/7/

Answer (score 0):

First step: change all the button names to `class="follow-me-btn"`

The code will look like this:

```
<a href="#" class="follow-me-btn follow-btn following charts">
```

You will also need to change the rest of your code slightly as you are, again, performing an operation on an entire group (all elements inside the "follow" class), rather than on one specific span element. Therefore, after changing the background color for `$(this)`, you must find the next `'span'` tag (or `'span.follow'` if you wish to be super-specific) and change the text in that specific span tag.

```
$('.follow-me-btn').mouseenter(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('follow-btn1')){
        $(this).css("background-color","red");
        $(this).find('span.follow').text("unfollow");
    }
});

$('.follow-me-btn').mouseleave(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('follow-btn1')){
        $(this).addClass("follow-btn1");
        $(this).css("background-color","green");
        $(this).find('span').text("following");
    }
});

$('.follow-me-btn').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('follow-btn1')){
        $(this).removeClass('follow-btn1');
        $(this).addClass('follow-btn');
        $(this).css("background-color","grey");
        $(this).find('span').text("Follow");
    }else{
        $(this).addClass("follow-btn1");
        $(this).css("background-color","#green");
        $(this).find('span').text("following");
    }
});
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/X39QY/6/)